# How to make BigDecimal division more precise

Tags: java, kotlin, rounding, bigdecimal, arbitrary-precision

I'm having an issue with `BigDecimal`s, the simplified idea is to:

- define a value for the `total`
- split the `total` in 3 `parts` defined by `weights`, these weights are 3 double values that add up to `100.0`
- sum up the `parts`
- the sum should be close to the `total`, the error should be at most 0.00000001

Here's the failing test:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun sanityCheckExampleForStackOverflow() {
        val whole = BigDecimal.valueOf(2_000_000_000.00)
        val weights = listOf("25.453778250984232", "35.38647064849812", "39.15975110051765").map { BigDecimal(it) }

        val parts = weights.map { weight ->
            // w / 100 * total
            weight.divide(BigDecimal(100)).times(whole)
        }

        val sumOfParts = parts[0] + parts[1] + parts[2]
        val difference = sumOfParts - whole

        assertTrue(difference <= BigDecimal("0.00000001"))
    }
```

What's missing?

Comment: Why are your weights initialized as double literals? Doubles are imprecise. They should be BigDecimals initialized with strings, otherwise you're potentially losing precision.

Comment: The doubles are then converted to BigDecimal using valueOf which uses the string representation of doubles.

Comment: It is too late by that point. The precision is already lost

Comment: I've updated the code and the example. It still fails with strings

Comment: Probably missing a MathContext to your division

Comment: @julien.giband That's for specifying scale (which I left out on purpose since I don't want to constrain it) or a rounding mode, which I don't need because there's no rounding happening

Comment: Your weights summed are 100.000000000000002, is that intentional?

Comment: @Michael it's a kotlin alias for multiply. Same thing.

Comment: @Michael `times` is defined as an extension method in Kotlin, see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/java.math.-big-decimal/

Comment: @PabloFernandez, just run your code and the test passes

Comment: Nevermind, I has my project ill-configured and the test didn't actually run. Saw "Failures: 0", but not "Test run: 0". Just needed to correct my previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your weights sum to 100.000000000000002, the value of `sumOfParts` is `2000000000.000000040`, which is `0.00000004` from your original value, which is four times bigger than the desired difference of `0.00000001`.

Comment: You're correct Mark. I was generating these numbers automatically using Double arithmetic. That explains the rounding error. Thanks for your answer.